# I want to save multiple textFields into a single string? how can i do it? #android #beginner

Tags: android

// i want to save all these textFields into a single string..please help

EditText editText, editText2, editText3, editText4, editText5, editText6, editText7, editText8, editText9, editText10, editText11, editText12;

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: String [] final_text_fields;
            final_text_fields = new String[]{editText, editText2,  editText3,  editText4,  editText5, editText6, editText7, editText8, editText9, editText10, editText11, editText12};

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add the code for your remaining EditTexts. I've added only 4

```
 StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append(editText.getText().toString());
    s.append(editText2.getText().toString());
    s.append(editText3.getText().toString());
    s.append(editText4.getText().toString());
    .........
  String strResult = s.toString();
```